# how to design a product table with user id and indexes?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a product table and have to design my db with this schema:

```
export interface IProduct {
  user_id: string;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  desc: string;
  photos: IPhotos[];
  video?: string;
  price: number;
  new_price?: number;
  sale?: {
    percentage: number;
    expires: Date;
  };
  sizes_and_colors: ISizeAndColors[] | [];
  category?: ICategorieWithGender;
  supplier?: Suppliers;
  shipping_days?: {
    min: number;
    max: number;
  },
  shipping_price?: number;
  stars?: IStars;
  status?: StatusProductType;
};
```

In product I have two indexes, id of product and user_id (nonclustered).

```
CREATE TABLE product (
 id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
 user_id UUID REFERENCES users(id),
 name VARCHAR,
 info VARCHAR NULL,
 price DECIMAL(10, 2),
 new_price DECIMAL(10, 2) NULL,
 category VARCHAR,
 sub_category VARCHAR,
 supplier VARCHAR NULL,
 situation VARCHAR COMMENT 'Situation of the product like new or used',
 status SMALLINT DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Is the product active for 1 or inactive for 0',
 created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 INDEX I_P_UID NONCLUSTERED(user_id)
)
```

my question is now, I also make select condition like where category = ..., so should I set a index for category and sub category ? and are too much indexes not bad ?

for star rating, photos, sale and shipping and variants I make for each a own table or is it bad ?

Comment: Wondering why a product would reference a user – unless that 'user' actually is the manufacturer – but then there's supplier as well? And wouldn't a supplier possibly have multiple products? So for supplier, but as well category and sub-category it *might* be meaningful to provide a separate table. Avoids problems with same supplier/category/... having different strings (possibly differing in case or whitespace).

Comment: Situation seems to encode a fix set of given values, so then I'd prefer integral values as well.